# Can't update list view in DisposableObserver?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, rx-java

I am newbie in RxJava and RxAndroid. I'm trying to search the keyword in an array and if any data found i'm trying update in list view using adaptor. But application got struck and not movie further. Could you any one help on this requirement. I'm attaching what I have tried...

Thanks in advance

```
  val dataArray = ArrayList<CisData>();
        var cisDataAdaptor : CisDataAdaptor ;
        var isFirst = true
        Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<CisData> { e ->

            var word = "Test"

            val search = ".*$word.*"

            val regex = Pattern.compile(search)

            for (index in resources.getStringArray(R.array.list).indices) {

                if (regex.matcher(resources.getStringArray(R.array.list).get(index)).find()) {

                    e.onNext(CisData(resources.getStringArray(R.array.list_of_kural).get(index), (index + 1).toString()))

                }
            }

            e.onComplete()
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                        object : DisposableObserver<CisData>() {
                            override fun onNext(response: CisData) {

                                dataArray.add(response)

                                if (isFirst) {

                                    cisDataAdaptor = CisDataAdaptor(context, dataArray)
                                    list_view!!.adapter = cisDataAdaptor
                                    isFirst = false

                                } else {
                                    cisDataAdaptor!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                                }
                            }

                            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                            }

                            override fun onComplete() {
                            }

                        })
```

Comment: Try making `var isFirst = true` a member of the anonym `DisposableObserver`.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,but In my application I'm declaring `isFirst` as a global member of the activity

Comment: Do you get an error in `onError`? How is the application "stuck"? Should `cisDataAdaptor!!.notifyDataSetChanged()` executed only for the last of the items, but no the first?

Comment: No I didn't get any error in `onError` method. After few second I'm getting the error in pop-up like `APP isn't responding` and asking  `close app` or `wait`

Comment: In the log-cat i'm getting following error `Thread[3,tid=1291,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x7f8144f400,peer=0x12c8e160,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3`

Comment: Try logging in `onNext` and see if you are overwhelmed or not.